# Symfony 2 + ajax Twitter-like load more content

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I am creating a page where I can load more "news" on frontpage. There are now 4 "news", and when I press button Load More, it should load 4 new news.

I know how to do it with plain php and ajax. But I have no idea how to do it with Symfony 2.

Using this site, code example as source, http://www.9lessons.info/2009/12/twitter-style-load-more-results-with.html

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate route for get more news e.g `news/get/[index]` then your controller fetch the news objects from db and output as json formate e.g,

```
public function yourControllerAction(){
  $news = //objects fetched from db

  //set json header
  $response = new Response();
  $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  $response->setContent(json_encode($news);
  return $response;
}
```

And then in your page you can populate it with using raw javascript or javascript templating engines like `mustache`. You can also check [JMSSerializerBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle/master/usage) for fine tuning json output.

Answer (score 0):

Your most simple approach would be to use an embedded controller:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers

Give it a value that defaults to 0 or something similar (I would suggest the news id). Then the embedded controller loads the latest 4 news if the news id is 0, or would load the next 4 news that come after the id you supply, which would be the id of the last news you displayed.

No code duplication.